# FileField: How to use upload_to with a whitespace in the name and path

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that allow me to upload a file, but for some reason the whitespace defined in the custom `upload_to` function get replaced by underscore in the file system(or in s3) for both the filename and the folder path.

**Is there a way to enforce the use of whitespace?**

eg:
The file "hello world.png" become "hello_world.png"

ps: I know this is a bad practice to use whitespace, but it's not my choice .

Here is the code:

## models.py

```
one_file = models.FileField(
    _('My label'),
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    upload_to=one_file_name,
    max_length=500,
    #part for s3, using the local media doens't change anything
    storage=PrivateMediaStorage(),
)
```

## my upload_to function

```
def one_file_name(instance, filename):
    extension = filename.split(".")[-1]
    return f'folder name/subfolder name/{filename}.{extension}'
```

Comment: note that `upload_to` specifies the directory to upload the file, not the final filename. So with your settings, the file would be saved as folder/subfolder/filename.ext/filename_45ef8a.ext

Comment: whitespaces in a file name would cause an error in the url. If you need the name without spaces, save it in another model attr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

space in file name cuase an error in url anyway I think this could help to you ,Django calls get_valid_filename() to make some alterations to filenames when saved - specific to your case, spaces are replaced with underscores or anything you want. [You can find the full docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/utils/text/) here. Here's the function itself:

```
@keep_lazy_text
def get_valid_filename(s):
    """
    Returns the given string converted to a string that can be used for a clean
    filename. Specifically, leading and trailing spaces are removed; other
    spaces are converted to underscores; and anything that is not a unicode
    alphanumeric, dash, underscore, or dot, is removed.
    >>> get_valid_filename("john's portrait in 2004.jpg")
    'johns_portrait_in_2004.jpg'
    """
    s = force_text(s).strip().replace(' ', '_')
    return re.sub(r'(?u)[^-\w.]', '', s)
```

Comment: This is the function I try to find for 2 hours now! I will dig a litle bit to see if I can make it works.

Comment: How can one stop `Django` from calling the `get_valid_filename()` function. It is useful in some situations.

Comment: @Gathide, you can write custom `Storage` class and override its `get_valid_name()` method. Here's the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-file-storage/.