# How can i send files who have spaces in their name in my django app

Tags: django, python-3.x

I will like to be able to send files in email in this django project. But files with spacies in their names seem not to go through, also when selecting the files to be sent i am able to select multiple files but only one file will go through the others are not recieved in mail.

Views.py

```
import os
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from .forms import EmailForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
from datetime import datetime
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

def email1(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EmailForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.published_date = datetime.now()
            post.save()
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        subject = request.POST.get('subject') 
        message = request.POST.get('message')
        document = request.FILES.get('document')
        email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        recipient_list = [email]
        email = EmailMessage(subject,message,email_from,recipient_list)
        base_dir = 'media/documents/'
        try:
            for i in document:
                email.attach_file('media/documents/'+str(document))
                os.rename(document(document.replace(' ', '_')))
                email.send()
                return render(request, 'sendmail/sendmail.html')
        except:
            pass
    else:
        form = EmailForm()
        return render(request, 'sendmail/sendmail.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ClearableFileInput
from .models import Mails

class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control", 'id': "clientemail"}))
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))
    document = forms.FileField(widget = forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple':True}))
    subject = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}))

    class Meta:
        model = Mails
        fields = ('email', 'subject', 'message', 'document',)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Mails(models.Model):
    email =     models.EmailField() 
    subject =   models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=20000)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Comment: Is the file not found anywhere with an altered name? Reading around in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56475978/filefield-how-to-use-upload-to-with-a-whitespace-in-the-name-and-path) post I would expect the file to be found in the directory with the white space replaced. If the file is not found, are you getting any errors?

Comment: I want the file to come from the user hence the variable(document).